# SQL Server Database Design - multiple columns in one table reference single column is another table

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm designing my first SQL Server database and wonder if there's a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

The goal is to be able to create one of 14 documents based on 200+ different document sections (titles, headings, paragraphs, lists, etc). Each document section is part of 1 or more documents.

My application does a single database lookup for a particular document and retrieves the data stored in the 50 text fields.

To do this, I first stored each unique document section in a "sections" table, giving each section a unique identifier (sectionID) and made the identifier a primary key, for example:

```
dbo.sections
sectionID(pk)       sectionText
iv1                 this is the text for the first section
AHv1                this text is for another section
APv2                more text to include
.
.
.
EFv3                another text section
GHv2                this is the last section text in the table
```

I then created a second table called "documents" to store each document name and the sections that belong to it. There are 51 columns in this table. The first column is the document name and the other 50 columns store the id's of the sections (they're named section1, section2, ...) that make up that particular document. Each of the section columns are foreign keys that reference the primary key in the "sections" table, for example:

```
dbo.documents
docID         section1(fk)   section2(fk)   ... section50(fk)
option1         iv1           AHv1          ...   GHv2
option2         iv1           APv2          ...   EFv3
```

All of this seems straightforward to me. However, in order to get the text for each document to be part of a given record, I have to create a view that does 50 joins of the sections table. By doing that, each document id and its text are stored in one row of a table.

Is there a better way to get the same end result? Or a better design? It seems like there may be a lot of overhead to join the data between tables.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have one table, `document`, with a one-to-many relationship with a second table, `documentSection`.  `Document` has a PK field `documentID`, `documentSection`'s PK is compound, `documentID` and `sectionID`, so when the two tables are joined, it's only on the `documentID` field.  Then you won't need one column for each section.

Actually, it sounds like you have all of the document section text stored in your `section` table, which can be used in multiple documents.  Maintenance nightmares aside, you can have `Section` be your primary table and `sectionDocument` have the one-to-many relationship, but you may need to introduce a `sectionSequence` field to keep the sections of your document in sequence.  You'll actually need the sequence field regardless of which table is primary.

---

regarding your comment, let's say you have a `section` table with a PK field `sectionID`.  Then you can have a `sectionDocument` table with a compound PK, `sectionID` and `documentID`, which will probably need to include a `sequence` number.  You're currently using the ordinal position of the column to identify the sequence of the section in the document, but as you say, you don't want 50 relationships to the `section` table.  The way to handle that is to have the sections defined vertically instead of horizontally.  In rows instead of columns.  You can also have a `document` table with PK `documentID` and the document `name`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Beth. The sections table is the primary and each row in the document table is a document record whose columns reference the various sections that make it up. I'm not sure how I'd put the documentID in the section table without having to duplicate text, in which case I'd only need one table. Maybe you're suggesting having 3 tables - one with section text and id's, one with document id's, and one with document id's, section ids, and sequence numbers?  As I said, this is the first time I've tried to create a database, so I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

Building on (and maybe clarifying) what Beth is talking about, you might consider a three-table approach. The lords-of-data generally refer to *normalization rules* or *normal forms* to describe patterns in your data that result in great flexibility and performance.

At first blush, these rules seem to spread your data out, but it's very worthwhile learning about these patterns. You don't have to worry about your database "joining a lot" as this is what relational databases are really good at - and *normalized* database are really easy to join up.

[image: The Schema]

For example, in order to select all the section texts *in order* for a given document, you would do something like this:

```
select
    s.SectionText
from
    Documents d
    inner join
    DocumentSections ds
    on
        d.DocumentId=ds.DocumentId
    inner join
    Sections s
    on
        ds.SectionId = s.SectionId
where
    d.DocumentId = 'MyDoc'
order by
    ds.Position
```

Basically, this converts your 50 columns in documents to an unlimited number of rows in DocumentSections.

Here's how you'd define such a system in SQL Server:

```
create table dbo.Sections
(
    SectionId
        nvarchar(8) not null
        constraint [Sections.SectionId.PrimaryKey]
            primary key clustered,

    SectionText
        nvarchar( max ) not null
)

create table dbo.Documents
(
    DocumentId
        nvarchar(8) not null
        constraint [Documents.DocumentId.PrimaryKey]
            primary key clustered,

    Name
        nvarchar( 255 ) not null
        constraint [Documents.Name.Unique]
            unique nonclustered

)

create table dbo.DocumentSections
(
    DocumentId
        nvarchar(8) not null
        constraint [DocumentSections.to.Documents]
            foreign key references dbo.Documents( DocumentId )
            on delete cascade,

    SectionId
        nvarchar(8) not null
        constraint [DocumentSections.to.Sections]
            foreign key references dbo.Sections( SectionId )
            on delete cascade,

    Position
        int not null,

    constraint [DocumentSections.DocumentId.SectionId.PrimaryKey]
        primary key clustered( DocumentId, SectionId ),

    constraint [DocumentSections.DocumentId.Position.Unique]
        unique ( DocumentId, Position )
)
```

There are a couple of things worth noting:

1. In this code, if you delete a row from `Documents`, the `DocumentSections` rows also go away (but not the `Sections` that were used in the `Documents` row). Likewise, if you delete a `Sections` row, the `DocumentSections` rows for that deleted `Sections` row go away, leaving the Documents unmolested. This is done with the `on delete cascade` clauses in the foreign key constraints. They're totally optional, but I showed it just for fun. This is often *very* handy.
2. I added a restriction (again optional) that prevents a Section from being used more than once in a Document. If that's not what you want, you can just remove that whole constraint.
3. I picked `nvarchar(8)` for the size of the key fields - for no particular reason. If you make these bigger, be sure to increase the width in the referring tables, too.